# Закрытие вкладки при повторном нажатии

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, вкладки

Добрый день. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно сделать закрытие вкладки при повторном нажатии? И еще один момент: как прятать блок '.bobs' при открытии любой вкладки? Спасибо большое за помощь!

```js
$(".social_icons>a").click(function() {
        
        $(".social_icons>a").removeClass("current");
        $(this).addClass("current");
        
        $(".social_container>div").hide();
        t_content=$(this).attr("href");
        $(t_content).show('500');

        return false
    });
```

```css
.social_container { width:300px; height:50px; background: chocolate; }
.social_container > div { display: none }
.social_icons > a.current { background: aqua; }
.bobs { width:100px; height:100px; background: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="social_icons">
    <a href="#content1">Вкладка 1</a>
    <a href="#content2">Вкладка 2</a>
    <a href="#content3">Вкладка 3</a>

    <div class="social_container">
      <div id="content1">Содержимое 1</div>
      <div id="content2">Содержимое 2</div>
      <div id="content3">Содержимое 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="bobs"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В обработчике клика проверяйте кнопку на то, есть ли у нее класс `.current` или нет. Например, так:

```js
$(".social_icons>a").click(function() {
  if (!$(this).hasClass('current')) {
    $(".social_icons>a").removeClass("current");
    $(this).addClass("current");

    $(".social_container>div").hide();
    t_content = $(this).attr("href");
    $(t_content).show('500');

    $('.bobs').hide();
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass("current");
    $(".social_container>div").hide();
    $('.bobs').show();
  }
  return false
});
```

```css
.social_container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  background: chocolate;
}

.social_container>div {
  display: none
}

.social_icons>a.current {
  background: aqua;
}

.bobs {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="social_icons">
  <a href="#content1">Вкладка 1</a>
  <a href="#content2">Вкладка 2</a>
  <a href="#content3">Вкладка 3</a>

  <div class="social_container">
    <div id="content1">Содержимое 1</div>
    <div id="content2">Содержимое 2</div>
    <div id="content3">Содержимое 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="bobs"></div>
```

Comment: @LADYX не совсем понял что за прокрутка

Comment: @LADYX попробуйте первую строчку исправить на `$(".social_icons>a").click(function(e) {` и следующей строкой дописать `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: Судя по всем, это совершенно другая тема. Возможно, стоит задать новый вопрос, добавив воспроизводимый проблему пример. А тут вы все таки спрашивали про закрытие вкладки)